# Fixing a URL coming into a javascript app?

Tags: javascript, url, mobile, encoding

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

I have a hybrid iOS app that has been compiled already. When it loads it pulls in a URL remotely that looks similar to this:

```
https://apps.somedomain.com/client?ai=6237&di=38401
```

However, the service that is providing that url is encoding the "&" as "%26".

I can not change the how the service is serving the variable to the app and I can not change the code in the app since it has already been compiled.

However, I can change the structure of the URL (though it still needs to point to the same place)

Does anyone know if there is a way around this without the need to go back into the app, account for the encoding, and recompile and re-submit the app?

Thanks for your help!

Rich

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you can and cannot change...would a URL like this be an option? `https://apps.somedomain.com/client/ai/6237/di/38401`

Comment: you are going to need more details on what you can change or not before you get a good answer, I suggest examples

Answer (score 0):

if you know that the url is always `escaped` you can simply add something like:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("%26") !=-1)
{
  window.location.href = unescape(window.location.href);
}
```

this way your app simply redirects to the correct url if it detects an escaped url.

Comment: Alex - thank you for the answer - I'm trying to find a way to fix this without having to go back into the code, however. Otherwise I need to do a recompile and re-submit and all that jazz.

Comment: ah, sorry I miss read. no I think that the ampersand is a standardized variable delimiter